# String variable and echo (C) *Homework*

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, keyboard

I am trying to solve this question: Write a C program that reads in characters from the keyboard until the return key is entered and echoes the entered text on the screen.

This is what I have so far, I am not sure what variable I can store the users input in so that I can print it back (assuming that is what they mean by echo):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
int main ()
{
    char sentence;
    printf("Please enter anything you want: ");
    scanf("%c",&sentence);

    printf("%c",sentence);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char` is a single character. You want to have an array of a sufficient length, and the corresponding format specifier `%s`.

Comment: Did you read any C book, C tutorial or do any basic research by hitting your favourite search engine?

Comment: `int ch; while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') putchar(ch);` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY This won't look nicely with keyboard input..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all you need is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf( "Please enter anything you want: " );

    int c;

    while ( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n' )
    {
        putchar( c );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

That is you need to use a loop that will iterate until the Enter key is pressed.

Comment: Depending on `stdin/stdout` buffering, might this intermix the typed data with output data?

Comment: @chux In the assignment there is noting said about this.:)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `getchar` which returns a single character from stdin.

```
int character;
while (character != EOF && character != '\n') {
    character = getchar();
    putchar(character);
}
```

Alternatively, you can make an assignment inside the while loop.

```
int character;
while ((character = getchar()) != EOF && character != '\n')
    putchar(character);
```

Comment: 1st version is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: `int character;
while (character != EOF && character != '\n')` uses `character` before it is initialized/assigned.